# Pipe two command outputs into one command

Tags: sqlite, batch-file, pipe

I'm trying to create a batch file to make wrting code in sqlite3 easier, and I want to my file to display the table, nicely, after all the edits made. I'm using Windows 10.
Here's the code:

```
echo .mode columns | sqlite3 somedb.db
echo select * from blah | sqlite3 somedb.db
```

I want `.mode columns` and `select * from blah` to be passed(piped) into the stdin of one `sqlite3 somedb.db`.

Comment: `( echo .mode columns & echo select * from blah ) | sqlite3 somedb.db`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need to use a pipeline, the commands can be [entered as arguments](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#using_sqlite3_in_a_shell_script) after the database name like so:

```
sqlite3 somedb.db ".mode columns" "select * from blah;"
```